# C test generator for load

Tags: c

I am trying to create a function that sends 100 call per second, and increase to 200 call per second every 60 second. The code is below

```
for (i = 1; i <= 240; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 100; j++) {
          send_tcp();
        }
        sleep(1);
        if(i %60 == 0) j=j+200;
        else j = j*1;
}
```

The send_tcp() is basically just open a socket, and send TCP to a certain address. The problem is, for j = 100, it sends every second correctly. However, when j=300, it goes to 3 second to send 300 tcp, and it takes 10 second to send 500 tcp request. Basically when the j goes in number, I can not get j call/second.

I am thinking this is just a logic mistake, but I can not figure out how to send J call/second, no matter what number j is...

Would Appreciate for any response

--sorry for my bad english, basically I need to do j number of "send_tcp" / second. However, when J goes bigger, it appears that J number of "send_tcp" is not / second but becomes / 3 seconds or more..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a logic error.  You are confusing your loop counter with the number of iterations you want.  This is what you need to do instead:

```
int n_calls = 100;
for (i = 1; i <= 240; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n_calls; j++) {
          send_tcp();
        }
        sleep(1);
        if(i %60 == 0) n_calls+=200;

}
```

Comment: ah yes thank you for pointing this. I also made this mistake. but if you try this, if n_class is for instance 500, one loop of send_tcp() will takes way longer then 1 loop of  100 send_tcp(). If 100 send_tcp can be sent in 1 second, each 500 send_tcp() maybe might take 3 second to finish. while actually I need to send n_calls per second, no matter how big the n_calls are. (sorry, its difficult to express this in english.. but I hope I deliver my intention)

Comment: Your objective of "send n_calls per second, no matter how big the n_calls are" is not achievable.  You would need unlimited bandwidth and processing power.

Comment: yes the intention is that, but I limit it to 100,300,500. But the result is that for 100 request is executed Per second, but for 300 and 500, it takes longer. Thus it is making the server side difficult to capture the exact time to process ... How can I send for example n_class = 500/seconds (not 3 seconds) for this matter?

Comment: It takes a certain amount of time to open and close the sockets and send the data.  Even for 500 calls that may be taking more than a second.

Comment: yes you are correct. for measurement of cps, I need to divide the number of packets per time, to get the number of cps.. As as you said, there is a number of limitation in the socket open and close. thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

You always loop in the second `for` from 0 to 100, it is 101 times. You change the value of J but then when the `for` starts it sets the value of `J` to 0 again. If I understand what you want to do, it is change the number of times the `send_tcp` is called when `i` increases. Then you need to change your code to something like that:

```
count_j=100;
for (i = 1; i <= 240; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= count_j; j++) {
          send_tcp();
        }
        sleep(1);
        if(i %60 == 0) count_j+=200;

}
```

is it what you want?